# jQuery Tools Tab Plugin: Make Active Tab Always first

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tools

I'm using jQuery Tools' tab plugin to do a vertical tab system (tabs vertically stacked on the left, with the related content on the right).

As you click on a tab, the content on the right changes. Works fine.

Is there a way though to make the current/active tab always be the first (or top) tab in the list?

```
<div class="corpRespPod" id="notes">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href="#notes" title="Tab 1">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#notes" title="Tab 2">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#notes" title="Tab 3">Tab 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="panes">
            <div>
               Tab 1 content Here
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
</div>
```

Simple JS to fire it:

```
    $("#notes .tabs").tabs("#notes .panes div");
```

So in other words, if "Tab 2" were clicked, it obviously adds the class of current, but also makes it the first `<li>` in the list. Any ideas of a CSS or JS solution? Doesn't seem to be in the native jQuery Tools functionality.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what your question is?  What you have already thought about doing?

Comment: My question is how to get the "active" ``<li>`` in the .tabs to always be the top/first in the unordered list. Was considering some sort of positioning, but seems overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure about jQuery Tools but with jQuery UI seems to be very straight forward

Check this demo using jQuery UI, it might help.

[Vertical Tabs jQuery](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/tabs/vertical.html)

Comment: via jQuery Tools, I've already got working what your link has. The problem I am running into is getting whatever the current one is always move to the top of the navigation (or first).

Comment: That's why I suggested jquery ui, because it won't change the order of your li tags

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="corpRespPod" id="notes">
   <ul >
    <li class="tabs" id="firstTab"></li>
    <li class="tabs">Tab 1</li>
    <li class="tabs">Tab 2</li>
    <li class="tabs">Tab 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    $("#notes .tabs").tabs("#notes");
});

$(".tabs").click(function(){
    $("#firstTab").text($(this).text());
    $(this).hide();
    $(".tabs").not(this).show();
});​
```

this is how ur selected tab would always be first one. and there will always be 3 tabs in your DOM.

**EDIT:** I had synced above code with my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/8pkXW/28/). Now plug and check it

Comment: And then I use CSS to position them?

Comment: No. When you will click a tab its <li> will remove and all its contents will pass to your auxilry <li id="firstTab"> which is always at first position. So your selected Tab will always show on first position.

Comment: Hmm, definitely seeing it working properly in your jsfiddle, but when I integrate it into my code, on click, it makes the tabs all disappear, leaving only the selected tab's associated content area.

Answer (score 1):

I would [use jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) to remove the DOM node and insert it again at the front of the tab list.  You could make it look good by calling jQuery's slideUp and/or slideDown methods (or [another animation method](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)) and relying on callbacks to order the animations.  jQuery's effects come built in with callbacks.

Comment: This sounds promising and I will work on a solution along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

What's your css on the li.current? I had this same thing happen when I accidently put a position:absolute on li.current.